# 64bit vs 32bit Windows server 2008

Tags: 64-bit, windows-server-2008

I have an HP ML350 G3 machine with a Xeon CPU. The machine has several 64 bit expansion slots, but if I try to install 64 bit OS it says I have a 32 bit CPU. how can a 32 bit CPU have 64 bit slots?

Comment: Just for a little more context [system overview](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c00409056&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=316537) and [processor specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/27278/Intel-Xeon-Processor-3_06-GHz-512K-Cache-533-MHz-FSB)

Answer (score 4):

The 64-bit PCI-X expansion slots are simply double-width versions of the standard 32-bit ones, to provide higher bandwidth. They have nothing to do with the actual CPU architecture.

See here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-X

If the CPU is 32-bit, then you can only install a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I kinda figured that was what was going on, seems kinda like false advertising to me :)